# Android app isn't found when searching for its title

Tags: android, google-play

I published my first app "FitFit Gym & Fitness Notebook" on friday and it can be found when searching for the full title.
But when I only enter "gym" or "fitness" it isn't found at all, even if I scroll down to the bottom of the page. I understand that it isn't listed at the top results because it is new and has not enough downloads, but I think it should be listed *somewhere*.

Is it possible Google filters my app out of the results for any reason?

Comment: afaik it stops around the #500th app

Comment: The full name of WhatsApp on Play Store is **WhatsApp Messenger** and that is shown when I search for **messenger**. So I guess you don't have enough downloads yet

Comment: By the way you should add a play store tag too to your question

Comment: Okay I didn't know it stops around the 500th app, thought it loads endlessly until all are loaded.

Comment: Search for "android store optimization" or similar. Ranking depends on multiple things like number of searched keyword in description text, dowloads, user rating, backlinks,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is the the mechanism Google Play Store uses for ranking apps is proprietary and closely held. It is some algorithm based on key words in the description, popularity (rankings and downloads), etc.  You can influence it a bit with repeated key words in the description but not much, and too many repeated keywords may or may not hurt, but it won't help.

Get some users to start giving good feedback and high ranking and that should help your search favorability.